# Where can I find my Pokécoins in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I cannot find my Pokécoins in Pokémon Go!

I tried to look in the avatar shop, but I can't find them!

Is there other ways of finding Pokécoins?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can see your Pokecoins from the shop menu:

[image: Pokecoins in shop menu]

To access it, press the Pokeball icon to open the menu, then Shop.